# How to remove partial duplicates in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
1st column - nike (brand)
2nd column - nike shoes
3rd column - slippers nike
```

i want to remove nike from 2nd and 3rd column
is there any formulaa to remove it automatically. I can use replace option
But i have lot of brands to wrk
So replace option won't work
another example:

```
1column - puma
2column- running shoes puma
3column- puma jogging walking shoes
```

need to remove puma only from 2nd and 3rd column with formulaa

I need to remove it and not find it as duplicates or unique

Comment: To edit a cell in-place will require a VBA macro.

Comment: You could use a helper column with the `FIND` formula and if it returns anything other than an error you know your value is in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Try the formula below.

```
=REPLACE(H10,FIND("nike",H10,1),LEN("nike")+1,"")
```